# PHP Require_once failed to open stream: Permission denied in ...Apache Xampp windows

Tags: php, windows, apache, xampp

Hi Ive been looking through answers and I cant seem to get this working
I'm trying to change my site through from php 5.6 to php7 and i've set up another xampp with php7 on to do this, I have the Vhosts pointed to the directory where all my files are and I cant this require_once to work
It throws a warning with the title message and it also throws:
Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'templates/'

I'm running off windows so I couldn't use that `chmod 777` but I checked the permission on the templates directory and the files in it and the SYSTEM one has all permissions
I read that Apache comes under SYSTEM permissions.
My include directory is pointed the same as before to the files

Im kind of at a loss here, any help would be really appreciated thanks

The code for include is

```
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>';
require_once("templates/" . $GLOBALS['template']);
```

Comment: Review the results of `phpinfo()` in both of your environments and look for differences in things like the PHP include path. It sounds like you believe that they are the same but the problem you describe sounds like they may not be.

Comment: I just checked and its `include_path=".;C:\xampp\php\PEAR"` in both of them Thanks for responding though

Comment: And I just `checked safe_mode=Off` in both as well

Comment: Please show us the code that is doing the include. The include path you have is the default for a new installation of PHP FWIW.

Comment: Hmm okay, that path was different in my second installation and I changed it to the one in the first, everyone else where im working is using the same thing

Comment: Have you double checked that the templates directory exists below the directory where your script with the problem is? Have you verified the contents of `$GLOBALS['template']` to make sure it contains what you expect it to contain? Also double check the output of `phpinfo()` in the areas of where the script is actually be run from (in particular the `SCRIPT_FILENAME` value).

Comment: Yeah templates is a directory in the same directory from where the scripts is being run, $GLOBALS['template'] isnt null but its an object and i believe it to be the right one, I havent adjusted it and it works on all other branches of work. The script is being run from the index page which should be the correct page

Comment: I've never heard of an object being used in a require statement. Is it an object in the version that is working for you?